# Error on MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am having an issue with a query on Microsoft Access 2007. I've developed query which runs correctly when I run it from the query editor of Access. My problem is that I have put this very same query inside a string literal in a VBA code of a Report, on the event *On Open*' handler. My purpose is to assign this query to the property RecordSource of that Report, allowing the Report to be created dynamically with whatever query I want.

The issue arises when I actually open and run the Report. When the handler for the event Open finishes its execution I get the error: *you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression "ID" as part of an aggregate function*.

Here is the query (inside the VBA code for the open event handler).

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
   Dim Query As String
   Dim WhereClause As String

   WhereClause = [Forms]![Main Form]!
                 [WindowPrintOptions]![CustomizedReport]![txtResponsibility]

Query = "SELECT AllInfo.* 
         FROM (SELECT i.ID, 
                      i.[Number], 
                      i.Responsability.Value AS Responsability 
               FROM tbl_Projects AS p RIGHT JOIN 
                   ((tb_Items AS i LEFT JOIN tb_F_projects AS fp 
                     ON i.ProjectID = fp.Id) LEFT JOIN 
                     tb_items_comments AS ic ON ic.ItemID = i.ID) 
                     ON i.ProjectID = p.Id WHERE ( (i.Status = 'Status 1') 
                     AND (i.DateOpened >= #9/9/2014#) AND
                    (i.DateOpened <= #9/11/2014#) AND 
                    (i.DueDate >= #9/12/2014#) AND (i.DueDate <= #9/12/2014#) 
                    AND (i.Category = 'C1') AND (i.Deliverables LIKE '*' 
                    & 'dates' & '*') AND (i.Responsability.Value = 'Some name') 
                   ) ) AS AllInfo"
               Me.RecordSource = Query
    End Sub
```

Note that I don't use 'WhereClause' yet. It will be inserted afterwards into the query. I just removed it for the purpose of testing the query alone, and check if it was ok without any change and found it actually wasn't. So, just remembering: this very same query **does work** when I run it from MS Access query builder, but not here, dynamically. What may be the problem?

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint on `Query`? And also, after `Query`, type `Debug.Print Query` and update your question with the output, please.

Comment: @Invent-Animate, I did it. The *Debug.Print Query* call printed the very query I inserted. I copied it and pasted into the query builder and clicked "run". It worked properly. But the error during runtime goes on.

Comment: Great! What did it print?

Comment: You were supposed to update your question with what it printed out

Comment: Ok, I am doing so right now.

Comment: @Invent-Animate, I updated the question with the information you required.

Comment: Thanks! Now please copy that query into a new query. Does it still run if you create a query with that code exactly?

Comment: @Invent-Animate, I didn't get your last instruction. Should I copy the outcome of Debug.Print into my code, assigning it to a new variable (or the same old Query variable)? If this is what you intended, I did it and it did not work, since the queries are the same.

Comment: Sorry, no. You should create a new Query with that SQL. Leave VBA for a minute. I'm just making sure that what the debugger output will indeed run.

Comment: Got it. I created a new query using the MS Access editor. It worked, just as the old query. The problem goes on only in runtime, as before.

Comment: The Report has, by default, a query associated with its ReportSource property. Does it make any difference?  Furthermore, this query ia in a file and it is fundamentally the same query I introduce in the VBA code above..

Comment: Is the query that already exists throwing an error?

Comment: Not when I run it through the query editor. Only through VBA runtime.

Comment: No, the query that is already associated with the report

Comment: No. This query does not throw any error.

Comment: Just as a test, add, at the end of your query: `GROUP BY AllInfo.ID`